# create var in other python file

Tags: python, tkinter

im working on a library for creating a window in python. i want the user to be able to type:

```
#user file
from winpy import *

create_window()
```

and then type the properties in the hooks or below the function

these are the properties:

```
#liberary file
    #properties
    window_title = "Title"
    window_backgroundcolor = "#BDEAFF"
    window_height = 100
    window_width = 500

    window_text = "This is an message!"
    window_text_font = "40"
    window_text_x = "center"
    window_text_y = "center"

    #center x and y
    if alert_text_x == "center":
        alert_text_x = alert_width / 2

    if alert_text_y == "center":
        alert_text_y = alert_height / 2
```

**the problem** is that if i type the properties in the other file it gives me an error.

can someone help me with this

If its needed this is the entire library so far.

```
#liberary file
def create_window():
    #properties
    window_title = "Title"
    window_backgroundcolor = "#BDEAFF"
    window_height = 100
    window_width = 500

    window_text = "This is an message!"
    window_text_font = "40"
    window_text_x = "center"
    window_text_y = "center"

    #center x and y
    if alert_text_x == "center":
        alert_text_x = alert_width / 2

    if alert_text_y == "center":
        alert_text_y = alert_height / 2
    # alert window
    root = tk.Tk()

    canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height=alert_height, width=alert_width)
    canvas.pack()

    canvas.create_text(alert_text_x, alert_text_y, text = alert_text, font = alert_text_font)

    root.title(alert_title)

    print("window created succesfully")

    root.mainloop()
```

this is the error im getting:

File "g:/codes/python/winpy/app.py", line 5
alert_title = "Alert!"
^
IndentationError: unexpected indent

Comment: Please update your question with specifics of exactly what code is in which file (full name) and which folder (full name) they are in. And edit the __full__ error message into your question as text not a screenshot/picture

Comment: @barny good idea, i did it.

Comment: Please edit the full error message into your question.

Comment: I don't see any details of which code is in which file in which folder.

Comment: @barny they are in the same folder

Comment: I __still__ don’t see any details of the FULL error message. Not sure why this is so difficult.

Comment: @barny the error message is there

Comment: I __still__ don’t see details of the file names and folder names for each piece of code. And the error message appears to refer to code you haven’t shown. That’s just about tab/spec indenting of your Python code. I give up, this is not a productive use of my time.

Answer (score -1):

Have you imported the file in which you defined variables in your main file? If you havent try doing it.
import name_of_your_file as something

Then when you need to access the variables.
Use
something.variable_name

Comment: So i would do like Filename.var = hello ?

Comment: You will do this when you'll be accessing it in an other file. Not in the file you define them.

Comment: it doesn't give me any errors. but when i change something in the user file it doesn't effect the output

Comment: What do you want to change. Can you please provide me with code snippets of both separate files.

Comment: @sheherbano the ful code of both files are on there